# What is the difference between generic server and server in weblogic?

Tags: weblogic, server

I am confused, what is difference between `generic web server` and `web server` in `weblogic`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Generic server** is a special server and run time implementation of base server tooling that can adjust its behavior by a server type definition file. Server type definition files are XML based meta information files that are introduced using "org.eclipse.jst.server.generic.core.serverdefinition" extension point.This document describes the different parts of the server definition files.

**WebLogic Server** implements Java 2 Platform, Enterprise Edition (J2EE) version 1.3 technologies (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/index.html). J2EE is the standard platform for developing multi-tier Enterprise applications based on the Java programming language. The technologies that make up J2EE were developed collaboratively by Sun Microsystems and other software vendors, including BEA Systems.
WebLogic Server J2EE applications are based on standardized, modular components. WebLogic Server provides a complete set of services for those modules and handles many details of application behavior automatically, without requiring programming.